# sequence $2,10,18,26,$.... contains no cube

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have came across the following problem:-
Show That The sequence $2,10,18,26,$.... contains no cube.

---

how can I able to solve this problem?can I get some help?

Comment: The $n$th term is $8n-6$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: work mod 8.  Look at elements of this sequence mod 8, and look at cubes mod 8.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:Any cube number on divsion by 8 leaves a remainder of $0,1,3,5,7$ and the all the numbers of the given sequence is leaves a remainder of $2$ on division by $8$.

Reason :Any square number leaves a remainder of $1$ on division 8$((2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=4k(k+1)+1=8c+1[\text{ as k(k+1) is even}])$ if the number is odd and else $0$ so cube leaves a remainder of $0,1,3,5,7$ on division by $8$.

Comment: don't miss $0$:)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is $8n+2$.

Suppose $8n+2=m^3$.
Mod 8, the cubes are
1:1, 8:0, 27:3, 64:0, 125:5, 216:0, and 343:7.

None are congruent to 2, so 8n+2 is never a cube.

Alternative proof:

If $8n+2=m^3$,
$m$ must be even.
But then $m^3$ is divisible by 8,
and 8n+2 is not divisible by 8.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the series is Arithmetic one with the common difference $=8,$ the first term being $2$

So, the $n$ the term will be $2+(n-1)8=8n-6$ which is even, so will be its cube root

If the cube root is divisible by $2,$ the number $8n-6$ must be divisible by $2^3=8$

But $8n-6=2(4n-3)\implies $ the highest power of $2$ in $8n-6$ is exactly $1$

Answer (score 1):

The terms are of the form- $8n+2=2(4n+1)$.So it has a factor 2 but is not divisible by 8.